# Simple Jquery selecting dom elements trying to copy images to another slider

Tags: jquery, image, dom, find

I want to copy the picture in a slider into another slider. Im using iOSslider if that helps.. Jquery is so complicated when browsing through the dom and i im this case i just fail time after time..

i want to select the img without the divs they are wrapped in. I want to selected them all dynamically and add them to something like a list which i then can append to another similar list..

here is my code

```
var scroll='<div  class="sliderContainer imageViewerExerciseMenu"><div id ="newSliderr" class ="iosSlider"><div class ="slider">'+
    '<div class="item"><img src="../images/exercises/MuscleGroup1.png"></div>'+
    '<div class="item"><img src="../images/exercises/MuscleGroup1.png"></div>'+
    '<div class="item"><img src="../images/exercises/MuscleGroup1.png"></div>'+
    '<div class="item"><img src="../images/exercises/MuscleGroup1.png"></div>'+
    '<div class="item"><img src="../images/exercises/MuscleGroup1.png"></div>'+
    '<div class="item"><img src="../images/exercises/MuscleGroup1.png"></div>'+
    '<div class="item"><img src="../images/exercises/MuscleGroup1.png"></div>'+
'<div class="item"><img src="../images/exercises/MuscleGroup1.png"></div></div></div></div>';
```

Comment: why is this a bad question? I know about jquery selecint and traversals however i suck at it. Was hoping someone in here could help me...

Answer (score 0):

i have this but this does not copy the elements to array. Cant seem to get the clone method working.

```
var listArray = new Array();
inputObject.children().find('img').each(function(){
     listArray.push($(this));});
```